# Браузер скачивает файл *.php

Tags: php, nginx, php-nginx

Проблема такова:
при обращении к web-сайту по ip, страница корректно открывается, но стоит обратиться по dns - mysite.test.ru браузер начинает скачивать индексный файл *.php

Конфиг nginx:

```
erver {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    root  /var/www/mysite/web;


    index index.php;
    # add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;


    # serve static files directly
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
            access_log off;
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }


    location / {
            # add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;

    }
}
```

Comment: В логи `nginx` заглядывали?

Comment: @Sergey Nudnov Почистил кеш браузера и все заработало